# creating graphs using matplotlib by not loading data from csv's

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to great a graph such as the one illustrated in the following link http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/load_converter.html. The only difference is my data is local to my machine and i load it from a database using my python script. The examples given on the site load the data from csv files, which is not what i want. Is it possible plot a graph from data structures such as lists using matplotlib?

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible. How about reading [Pyplot tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html), hmmm?

Comment: The example you linked to answers your question.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?  Along with what you _expect_ the code to do and what it _actually_ does.  Try to reduce your example down to the minimum needed to show your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to plot a graph from lists using matplotlib. This is perhaps the most straightforward usage case, please see the docs: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: i have seen this before but i need dates for the x axis

Comment: @godzilla Then make one of the lists a list of `datetime` objects.